# How get the quaterion with rotation in x,y,z that faces gameobect to ther gameobject in unity c#

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 3d, orientation, space

I have a Steerings system that have an align steering that aligns one object to other object.
That woks well.
So when I start to programming the face behaivour to face gameobject to other object using the Aling steering.
I want a steering that one object1 faces to other object2 contnuously that if object2 moves or stay in place the object1 rotate to face object1 this in all rotation axies.
The problem is:
I need to get the quaternion rotated in direction of vector in 3D space. That vector is the diference between position of two gameobjects in Unity.

The Face script is:

```
    Vector3 directionToTarget = target.transform.position - ownKS.position;

            //Debug.Log(directionToTarget+"ssssss");
SURROGATE_TARGET.transform.rotation =Quaternion.Euler(Utils3D.VectorToOrientation(directionToTarget));


            // Align with surrogate target
return Align3D.GetSteering (ownKS, SURROGATE_TARGET, targetAngularRadius, 
                                      slowDownAngularRadius, timeToDesiredAngularSpeed);
```

- I tried to do with Quaterion.Euler(vector.normalized). not working.

```
     vector = vector.normalized;
                    //  Debug.Log(vector.normalized+"v normaliyes");
                    Quaternion v = Quaternion.Euler(vector);
        Debug.Log(v.eulerAngles);
                        return v;
```

- I tried that :
  where m is the vector of diference position between two objects.

The funtion VectorToOrientation(vector3 m) is:

````
m = m.normalized;
            Debug.Log(m);
            Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(m, new Vector3(1,1,1));
            axis.Normalize();
            double anglex = Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(m, new Vector3(1,0,0)) / m.magnitude / new Vector3(1,0,0).magnitude);
            double angley = Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(m, new Vector3(0,1,0)) / m.magnitude / new Vector3(0,1,0).magnitude);
            double anglez = Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(m, new Vector3(0,0,1)) / m.magnitude / new Vector3(0,0,1).magnitude);
            Debug.Log(anglex*180/Mathf.PI + "x  "+angley*180/Mathf.PI+"y       z"+anglez*180/Mathf.PI);


```
````

I don't konw if you undestand the problem?
If you have questions?? You can ask me.
If anyone can help me??
Thanks